# nginx: setup a webmail for every domain (wildcard domain?)

Tags: nginx, subdomain, wildcard, webmail

I would like to setup a webmail `mail.` subdomain for every domain I have on my server, using nginx.

It seems to work on `https://mail.mydomain.com` but I can also access the webmail by visiting the server's IP address (https://x.x.x.x), which is not wanted.

Here is my conf file for the webmail:

```
###
# Webmail (Rainloop)
###
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mail*.;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mail*.;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-webmail.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-webmail.error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/rainloop;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            include fcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fcgi.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ^~ /data {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640813/2777965) the default Nginx config has been changed as follows:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  <ip_address_nginx_server>;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    return 403;
}

server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    }
}
```

Once the Nginx server has been restarted and one navigates to `ip_address_nginx_server` a 403 is returned, while `http://example.com` is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

According to Nginx documentation, it is possible to use this kind of wildcards in [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mail.*;
    ...
}
```

However, you are having `mail*.` instead of `mail.*` there, which is really a different thing.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I had in mind that wildcard; just a typing error.